# How to determine screws needed for a laptop

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair

I am working on my Acer Aspire 5742z-4685.

1. Where online can I find an exploded view on my laptop that shows all the laptop components, down to the laptop screws? I looked all over the Acer site but could not find any images/images of parts or even a list of parts for my laptop. I have also searched using Google images.
2. If there are no exploded views, how does one determine the laptop's components and their respective part numbers?

Comment: This should help: http://www.manualslib.com/manual/249194/Acer-Aspire-5742.html

Comment: [How to disassemble Acer Aspire 5742](http://www.insidemylaptop.com/how-to-disassemble-acer-aspire-5742-series-laptop/)

Comment: I am new to Superuser. Thanks AcerPL!!! This is the exact information I needed! **A BIG THANKS!!!** I was able to download the service manual for my 5742z and locate the needed screw sizes. I will also take a look at the disassembly instructions. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok. Mark it as an answer below. It will help reducing the unanswered questions backlog here on SE.

Comment: I just noticed that I am still missing one screw size:  Both the service manual, page 57, Removing the RTC Battery (UMA Only) , and the disassembly instructions, Step 4, "Remove one screw securing the hard drive.", show  **1 screw holding the hard drive in place.** Interestingly, in the service manual, in the Removing the HDD Module section, page 62, no screw is shown, thus, no screw size. Maybe it's a M2*3.  AcePL or anybody else, if you know what the HD retaining screw is, please let me know.

Comment: David, I just noticed that you posted the very helpful link to  
How to disassemble Acer Aspire 5742. A **BIG thanks** to you too.

Comment: I also own an Acer 5742z. Already disassembled it thrice, but can't remember exactly. Manual on p62 is incomplete (unfortunately, happens). There is extra screw holding HDD module in place, and it is M2, but I think it's longer one (*5)... But in this specific instance it doesn't matter, fortunately. The module is a tight fit, so sliding out takes some force and it really is held in place by 2 screws holding the "logic lower door".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For laptops there is - or should be - Service Manual. They were usually proprietary some time ago, but now they are available for free. Search for that in the future.

In the meantime this should help:
http://www.manualslib.com/manual/249194/Acer-Aspire-5742.html